# Strange behavior on Oracle CAST to NVARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT (CAST("META_SECT_ORDER" AS NVARCHAR2(3)) || '#' || "CODE") AS "SECTION"
FROM "BMAN_TP2"."LOADER_TEMPLATE_SECTIONS"
```

`META_SECT_ORDER` is obviously in integer, while `CODE` is a string.

It outputs 700 rows like these:

```
SECTION
-------
 0#F01
 0#I05
 1#I05
 2#I05
```

etc...

I know that `CAST` is not necessary but the query is composed by an underlying querybuilder that also outputs for MsSQL Server (where the `CAST` is needed) and Postgres.

The strange fact is that if I raise the `NVARCHAR2` length I obtain different results. For example:

- with values <= 80, I get the correct result (see above)
- with a value of 81, I get 700 rows of `쥴ឋ醴ఀ퉶൐凨쓥昁菄ࢋ䖼譕貉ႋ䖼莀鐋`
- with a value of 82, I get 700 rows of `ਖଆ`
- with odd values, in [83-127], I get 700 empty rows
- with even values, in [84-128], I get 700 rows of `ڢ`
- with values >= 129, I get `ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel`

What's that??

**EDIT :**

Actually, It seems that it depends only on the `CAST`, the concatenation is not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like "Bug 9949330 - ORA-7445 or garbled data casting a NUMBER to NVARCHAR2".  You've already discovered the official work-around, use values <= 80.

You should contact support to either download the patch or request one for your platform.

Here's an easier way to reproduce the issue without using any of your data.  It still fails as of 11.2.0.3.

```
SQL> select cast(level as nvarchar2(130)) from dual connect by level <= 1;

CAST(LEVELASNVARCHAR2(130))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ååååååååå┐┐┐ ┐┐  ┐┐A ┐┐  ┐┐A ┐┐  A   ┐┐  ┐   ┐┐  ┐┐A
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please link the documentation about this bug? I can't find it even with the bug # you wrote.

Comment: Sorry, Oracle's bug database is behind a paywall.  You'll need to sign up for an account on support.oracle.com, and then ask a DBA in your organization for the support ID.

Comment: Yes, I know.. I'm trying to access the Oracle support but it says that all services are currently unavailable for our account. I'll ask the sysadm, thank you.

Comment: I'm now able to see the bug description page. Thank you, accepted your answer.

Comment: For future reference, they states it's fixed on 11.2.0.3 *patch 11*